# capture special character from line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I would like to capture special character from a line:

```
var=`echo "#this is comment" | grep "[^a-zA-Z0-9 \t]"`
echo $var
```

Expected Output: `#`

But getting: `#this is comment`

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want something more like:

```
var=`echo "#this is comment" | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \t]//g;'`
```

Using `sed` will replace the characters; using `grep` was only searching for the characters.

Edit: Note that the `\t` construct is not guaranteed to be portable to all systems or locales; I believe if your `sed` supports POSIX regular expressions, using `[:space:]` may work better. (thanks @ghoti!)

Comment: The `\t` is not portable, and is ignored in OSX, BSD, Solaris, HPUX, etc.  The OP hasn't mentioned his platform.  If you want to include a tab, either use something portable, or specify the limitations of your answer.

Comment: `var=`echo "#this is comment" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9 \t]//g;'`` works charm, thanks for the quick response, you saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

```
string="#this is comment"
var=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]//g')
echo "$var"
```

I've removed `\t` as it's not portable.

If you want to do this with awk, as your tag suggests, you can use something like:

```
var=$(echo "$string" | awk '{gsub(/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/, "")} 1')
```

Note that these are probably *not* good ways to achieve whatever it is that you're trying to do.  If you post more of your code, showing us some context, we can help you avoid an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Of course, you can also do substitutions like this directly in bash, if you want.

```
var=${string//[A-Za-z0-9 ]}
```

You'll save CPU and time by avoiding the call to an extra program when you don't really need it.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can be used for this, but `tr` is a better choice:

```
echo "#this is comment" | tr -d 'a-zA-Z0-9 \t'
```

`tr` also supports character classes such as `[:space:]` and `[:alpha:]`